# Where can I find contests for extremely short stories?

Tags: contests

A while ago I've read an article describing  several literary contests of prose (maybe poetry too, I'm not sure) with extreme limits of words (or even symbols). Limits were about less than 1000 words or even 100 words.
Looks like I've lost that article and can't simply google that contests without it.
So anyone who know something about this format please give any info you have - contest names, links, articles about such contests etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely a flash fiction contest.  Flash fiction is generally limited to a certain amount of words or less, usually enough to make it a challenge to convey an interesting story.  If you google "flash fiction contest", you'll likely find a number of them.

As an example, Odyssey Con has their yearly [OddContest](http://www.odysseycon.org/contest/contest.html), in which submissions are limited to 500 words or less.

Comment: Yes, it is! I've also found in wikipedia several related terms which might be useful for those who want to dig this theme further:
Dribble, drabble, six-word story, 140-character story, sudden fiction, microfiction, minisaga.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Yahoo Group called [CRWROPPS-B](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/CRWROPPS-B/info;_ylc=X3oDMTJmc21oNXUyBF9TAzk3MzU5NzE0BGdycElkAzE2NzA3NjcxBGdycHNwSWQDMTcwNTE0Nzc2MARzZWMDdnRsBHNsawN2Z2hwBHN0aW1lAzE0ODcxNzgzMzc-) that distributes opportunities for writers, including flash and micro contests. Sign up for the email feed and you'll get tons of options. You'll have to go through the giant list occasionally to find what you're looking for, but you'll find what you're looking for there.